# Flashplayer support needed for starsports videos

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, flash

I know there is a problem with flash player. In my case I have 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 system. Youtube videos works fine, gifs works fine and even i have played flash games. 
But the problem is when I open starsports.com and click on any video it says flash player needed. Also on miniclip I don't see the game even loading.
What is the problem here?

Comment: What browser and what flash version (check [here](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)) do you use?

Comment: browser - firefox ,flash -11,2,202,569

Comment: Now please also add the terminal output of the command `dpkg -l *flash* | grep ^ii` to tell us which flash packages you have installed.

Comment: flashplugin-installer                       11.2.202.569ubuntu0.12.04.1           Adobe Flash Player plugin installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the site you want to visit requires a current version of Flash to work.

As Adobe officially stopped support for the NPAPI (plug-in interface in Firefox-like browsers) Flash version on Linux at version 11, that's the latest version you can get normally for Firefox.

However, there's a trick **starting with Ubuntu 15.10**. The Linux PPAPI (plug-in interface for Chrome-like browsers) Flash version is still getting upgraded and currently runs at version 19.

You can install the package `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` to temporarily download the Google Chrome browser in the background, automatically extract the latest PPAPI Flash plug-in from it and installing that. It also installs a PPAPI to NPAPI wrapper which makes this latest Flash version available for Firefox-like browsers as well.

---

Here's a list of all commands you need to run for the mentioned trick:

1. Purge the current Flash package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
   ```
2. Install the described PPAPI-to-NPAPI wrapper and the new Pepperflash plug-in extracted from Chrome:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
   ```

Then restart possibly running Firefox instances and visit https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ again to verify that you're now running a Flash version 19 or higher.

---

- Or simply install Google Chrome browser...
- or Chromium browser plus `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` (**available since 14.04**)

Comment: E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

Comment: installed chrome and it plays the required videos.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That package became available only since 15.10. I edited the answer to reflect that awareness.